# Wordpress automation with selenium

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium-webdriver, automation

My coworker send me video where I have to import 8 same blocks for each non main page. Earlier I was working with selenium, and I thought could I automate this?

So I came up with this code:

```py
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.safari.service import Service

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Safari()

browser.get('http://server.server.cz/wp-admin')

time.sleep(1)
Passname = browser.find_element(By.ID,"user_login")
Passname.send_keys('Name')

Password = browser.find_element(By.ID, "user_pass")
Password.send_keys('Password')

time.sleep(1)

submit = browser.find_element(By.ID,"wp-submit").click()

time.sleep(1)

submit = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="ab-item"]').click()
```

Im struggling to understand how selenium works because sometimes code will pass through login form to wordpress, sometimes it doesn't. Sometimes it will get an error with part of code before lines activations. CSS_SELECTOR and CLASS_NAME doesn't work. Click function doesn't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/justin/Desktop/projects/wordpressAutomation /main.py", line 30, in <module>
    submit = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"icon-options")
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 741, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {"using": by, "value": value})["value"]
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 347, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: ; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
```

Im sorry if I didn't specify any problem, Im starting to creating my ideas so if there is some information I forgot about please tell me and I will edit this question and please be patience if I don't understand something properly I will ask for proper direction. This is how I learn.

Comment: Did you disable the headless mode see where it fails?